# Are there commonly accepted graphic symbols for common declension forms?

Tags: declension, symbol

Some linguistic declension forms are found in many languages:

- Gender
- Singular / Plural
- Past, Present, Future
- Indication, Condition, Imperation
- Case: Nominative, Accusative, Dative etc.

Is there a more or less established set of graphic icons for these forms?

For Gender and Number it's quite easy:

- Gender: ♀ and ♂
- Singular and Plural:  and

However, for time, mode and case, it gets quite difficult to come up with something that a majority of people might understand. That's why I'm looking for an established set of icons. If there is not any, perhaps there is a well-known book like a thesaurus that uses such a set of icons?

Comment: What about three-gender languages?

Comment: @fdb yes. Would love to see a symbol for the third gender.

Comment: And what about languages with dual number, in addition to plural?

Comment: @theberzi yes, what about them. Answers are welcome.

Comment: I think your question has already been answered: if you're looking for something formally/conventionally used by people of the field, there is nothing but textual abbreviations: linguistics has many, many concepts to describe and some are very abstract. Icons could be obvious for some, but very confusing for others, and many icons that may seem obvious to us might not be so for other cultures.

Comment: @theberzi I agree, it has been answered mostly: there is no set of commonly used icons. However, there still might be a set of icons which are quite easy to understand. Maybe there is a series of grammar books which all use the same set. Please note that I do not need **all** concepts of **all** languages covered. But gender (dual), number (singular vs plural), case (at least nominative and accusative), time (at least past, present and future) and mode are used in many languages. Please note that abbreviations, too, can be obvious for some but very confusing for others.

Comment: Personally I would be hard-pressed to find something to intuitively represent even something as mundane as accusative case or indicative mood: they're concept so removed from the physical world that any symbol that could realistically represent them would just as easily confuse or be misinterpreted. The only way out I see is if a convention is established (say, a circle as a base and then a mark depending on the case), but that would still require the reader to know that context, hence it would not be intuitive anymore. A layman could find the concept itself hard, let alone the symbol for it.

Comment: @theberzi you assume that there is a requirement for the reader to understand the symbol without having seen it before. That would be nice, but it is not necessary. It's enough that the symbol is easy to learn and remember. My graphic designer already has some icons for the most important forms: the symbol for accusative has a person talking to someone while pointing at them. Dative would be a person giving something to someone else. People might not understand the symbol when they see it first, but after they have learned their meaning, they would remember well, I think.

Comment: The symbol for past is a clock at 11:50. Present is 12:00, future is 12:10. However, instead of coming up with our own symbols, we thought it would be better to have something that has already been used, so we don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 9):

As jk mentioned, linguists tend to use abbreviations rather than graphics for this. One standardized list is found in the appendix of the [Leipzig glossing rules](https://www.eva.mpg.de/lingua/resources/glossing-rules.php), which gives SG, DU, PL, etc for numbers, PST, PRS, FUT, etc for tenses, and so on.

These standards are often extended for individual languages, since it's extremely difficult to come up with a standard that covers *all* languages' genders, cases, and so on. In Bantu, for example, it's common to mark gender/class as C1, C2, C3, etc; in Sumerian, the unusual cases get new abbreviations like EQU for the equative ("this thing is like this other thing"); in Egyptian, nobody can agree on names for the tense-aspect combinations and different authors tend to make up their own abbreviations. But the standard is a good starting point, and the abbreviations on there will generally be quickly recognized (or easy to look up if they're not).

Comment: +1, thanks for the answer. I'm leaving the question open since I hope for an answer with a reference to a website / app / book which does use a set of icons.

Answer (score 6):

No. In fact, there aren't any graphics used for that purpose. Among linguists, abbreviations are used all over the place, and under [Universal Features](https://universaldependencies.org/u/feat/) you can find a representative set of abbreviations for common categories on different parts of speech.